# Mockito 5.0.0 Static Mocking Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am getting the following exception when trying to mock the static method.

static mocking is already registered in the current thread To create a new mock, the existing static mock registration must be deregistered

public class MockitoTest  {

```
MockedStatic<MyProperties> myPropertiesMockedStatic;

@Mock;
Student student;

@BeforeClass(groups = {"mocks"})
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    myPropertiesMockedStatic=Mockito.mockStatic(MyProperties.class);
    myPropertiesMockedStatic.when(() -> MyProperties.getProperty("document.abc.Id")).thenReturn("souJobId");

}

@Test(groups = {"mocks"})
public void testJobId() {
    try(MockedStatic<MyProperties> properties =Mockito.mockStatic(MyProperties.class)) {
        properties.when(()->MyProperties.getProperty("abc.url")).thenReturn("url");
        student.getStudentData();
    }
}
@Test(groups = {"mocks"})
public void testData(){
        myPropertiesMockedStatic.when(()->MyProperties.getProperty("abc.url")).thenReturn("testUrl");

        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Student st = new Student();
        list.add(st);
        //todo
   
}
@AfterClass(groups = {"mocks"})
public void cleanUp(){
    myPropertiesMockedStatic.close();
}
```

}

I'm a running multiple tests in different classes, the way we are using the myProperties individually then run fine, but when I run all of them at once, I get  For com.test.MyProperties, static mocking is already registered in the current thread. To create a new mock, the existing static mocking must be deregistered.

Is there any another way I can configure the , or is there a way to resolve this? I tried using different variable names for each of them but that doesn't work. Also tried close() on them after the test, but that doesn't seem to work, still getting getting the same issue for every classes.
If there's a way to do this via Mockito, without a try-with-resources for multiple objects and their behaviour, that would work for me as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just remove BeforeClass and AfterClass. Instead of openMocks use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) on class. In the testData method use try-with-resources too. And don't forget to remove MockedStatic<MyProperties> myPropertiesMockedStatic; from dependencies

Comment: I have already used this annotation on class level, but after using this my code coverage has gone down by 10%. And also that code i have shared, its working fine when i'm running only this class test cases but i'm trying to run whole module test cases then i'm getting this error